# Migration to .NET Core 2.0

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, migration, .net-core

I'm trying to migrate my project to .NET Core 2.0. 
I installed new SDK, changed target frameworks, and replaced `Program.cs` so my project runs well but i still get warning :

`Warning    AD0001 Analyzer 'RefactoringEssentials.CSharp.Diagnostics.FunctionNeverReturnsAnalyzer' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' with message 'Specified method is not supported.'.`

How can i fix this?

P.S: I used this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/

Comment: You should report this to the developers of Refactoring Essentials.

Answer (score 2):

Spent some time on their [website](http://vsrefactoringessentials.com/Features/Refactorings-CSharp) and its clear that they are targeting visual studio 2015, and 2017 dot net, and it looks like they have not rewired it for dot net core. That would explain the error you received.

Now, can you fix it? Well, since you did not design this extension, I guess you cannot. Not unless you choose to work on the code itself at their [GitHub](https://github.com/icsharpcode/RefactoringEssentials) repository, guess not. You just got to wait till they fix it.